# Connecting to Internet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, wininet

I'm having issues with connecting to the Internet using python.

I am on a corporate network that uses a PAC file to set proxies. Now this would be fine if I could find and parse the PAC to get what I need but I cannot.

The oddity:

R can connect to the internet to download files through wininet and .External(C_download,...) so I know it is possible and when I do:

```
import ctypes

wininet = ctypes.windll.wininet
flags = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
connected = wininet.InternetGetConnectedState(ctypes.byref(flags), None)
print(connected, hex(flags.value))
```

I get: 1 0x12 so I have a connection available but once I try to use other functions from within wininet I'm constantly met with error functions like:

```
AttributeError: function 'InternetCheckConnection' not found
```

and this goes for pretty much any other function of wininet, but this doesn't surprise me as the only named function in dir(wininet) is InternetGetConnectedState.

The wininet approach can clearly work, but I have no idea how to proceed with it [especially given that I only use Windows in work].

Comment: As far as I know, there's no need to _connect Python to the Internet_ as Python itself doesn't really care about this. Just make sure your computer is connected to the Internet and Python will automatically be able to use this connection.

Comment: When you say 'proceed with it' what do you want to do?

Comment: try importing the modules independently? `from ctypes.windll import wininet` `from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD` etc..

Comment: @BillBell if I try to do: with wininet.InternetOpen('blah') and then try to obtain a page's content I cannot because InternetOpen is not available.

Comment: @ForceBru ok, so poor wording - let's just change that to: open a connection to a web page and obtain its content using python

Comment: @Aaron no dice, makes no difference :(

Comment: @fūjin, `requests` Python module is great for this task

Comment: @ForceBru without having access to the proxy information from the PAC file how do you get it to be able to connect? Which handler? What configuration? [I've already seen pypac but it does not work on my machine because js2py does not have one of the built in functions that the version of pypac requires]

Comment: @fūjin, I dunno what PAC stands for, but if you must have this stuff to connect to the Internet, but can't get hold of it, how do you think Python will help you? I think, you could just go to the admins of the network at work and ask them to connect your computer to the Internet. When you don't have access to the Internet, it's like there's a huge indestructible wall between you and the "outer world" that has a tiny keyhole, so that an admin could put their key into it and let you out. The problem is, Python is a relatively big snake and can't squeeze through the keyhole :)

Comment: The thing to do is to try `requests`. If it doesn't work then show us what happened in a new question. Can you even install it?

Answer (score 0):

*"ok, so poor wording - let's just change that to: open a connection to a web page and obtain its content using python "*

Sounds like you actually need [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Here's a quick [example](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup) of them being used to explore a webpage

Answer (score 0):

First, I would *strongly* suggest to install the `requests` module. Doing HTTP without it on Python is pretty painful.

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/346376) you need to download `wpad.dat` from the host `wpad`. That is a text file that contains the proxy address.

Once you know the proxy settings, you can configure `requests` to use them:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```